# Why is result returning hex instead of actual value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's ROR Tutorial and for some reason my Users are getting returned in the browser as hex instead of their name.  Why is this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
@users = User.all
end

def new
end


end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
# attr_accessible :title, :body

has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followed_users, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name:     "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
```

has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower

```
def following?(other_user)
relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

def follow!(other_user)
relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

def unfollow!(other_user)
relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy!
end


end

<h1>All Users</h1>

<ul class="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
    <%= link_to user, user %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<% provide(:title, @user) %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="span4">
    <section>
        <h1>
            <%= @user %>
        </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
</aside>
<div class="span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not Hex, its returning an object.Try to print `user.name` or attribute or field you have in user table for user name. Try with :

```
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
```

instead of

```
<%= link_to user, user %>
```

and

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

instead of

```
<%= @user %>
```

## All Users

```
<ul class="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li>
    <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<% provide(:title, @user) %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="span4">
    <section>
        <h1>
            <%= @user.name %>
        </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
</aside>
```

Comment: I tried that before & I get an error saying undefined method `name' for #<User:0xb6ece01c>. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: I think you didn't defined user attributes in your User model. please paste your user migration code here.

Comment: class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
end

Comment: Now I understand, you dont't have name field in your table. You can print @user.email instead of user.name.

Comment: My apologies for the late response but thanks a lot that worked. Also I used public_activity and I'm having a similar problem with the event  showing up that a user's follower updates, any suggestions?

Comment: Post another question, and let me know about that. I will please to help you. Thanks

Comment: I just posted a new question regarding the public_activity gem

Comment: Did you check out my public_activity post that had this similar issue @railsguy

Comment: Just paste the URL of that question over here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747867/public-activity-returning-an-object-instead-of-result