# Public_Activity returning an object instead of result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I installed the public_activity gem following the railscasts tutorial. The activities page in the browser is returning an object instead of the actual event that the activity is referring to.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

Migration responsible for creating a table with activities:

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Create table
  def self.up
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.belongs_to :trackable, :polymorphic => true
      t.belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
      t.string  :key
      t.text    :parameters
      t.belongs_to :recipient, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :activities, [:trackable_id, :trackable_type]
    add_index :activities, [:owner_id, :owner_type]
    add_index :activities, [:recipient_id, :recipient_type]
  end

  # Drop table
  def self.down
    drop_table :activities
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you are getting? It could be an active record object.

Comment: Logged in as joeshmoe@yahoo.com. Edit profile | Logout Users
Friend's Activities
added new comment to #<Event:0xb707c1c>
added comment to #<Event:0xb67ee1c>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this to see if it works:

```
Activity.order("created_at desc")
```

I am just wondering if you have namespacing setup correctly.

I am not familiar with the way you are trying to namespace. Maybe give this a try:

```
Module PublicActivity
 class Activity

 end
end
```

or

```
 class PublicActivity::Activity < ActiveRecord::Base (or whatever class you want)

 end
```

Comment: Yes its in my ActivitiesController its the first code I posted

Comment: I am referring to the Model. Can you paste the content of your the model?

Comment: class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   include PublicActivity::Model
 tracked owner: ->(controller, model) {controller && controller.current_user}

 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
 validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}


end

Comment: See updated answer. I may be barking up the tree, but namespacing is always a hassle for me.